# Formatting the results of a glht in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, statistics, format, r-markdown

I want to format the results of a GLHT from multcomp package as a table in a Rmarkdown file, the output being a HTML.

```
library(multcomp)
post_hoc <- glht(tick_oneway, linfct = mcp(Habitat = "Tukey"))
summary(post_hoc)
```

I'm getting an error that Rmarkdown doesn't know what to do with the summary if I apply pander or kable or as_flextable.

```
## Warning in pander.default(summary(post_hoc)): No pander.method for
## "summary.glht", reverting to default.No pander.method for "glht", reverting to
## default.
```

I tried using kable, pander and flextable yet they all failed. I'm most likely doing something in order to display them in a Rmarkdown HTML document.

Does anyone know how can shape the output of summary so that the input is accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `tidy()` from the `{broom}` package, e.g.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(multcomp)
 # example from the package
  lmod <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
  K <- diag(length(coef(lmod)))[-1,]
  rownames(K) <- names(coef(lmod))[-1]
  ### set up general linear hypothesis
 post_hoc <- glht(lmod, linfct = K)


post_hoc |> 
  broom::tidy() |> 
  dplyr::mutate(signif = gtools::stars.pval(adj.p.value)) |> 
  kableExtra::kbl(digits = 2) |> 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```
````

[image: example_kbl]

Comment: I tried using this in markdown but after that all future chunks in the document were compressed and aligned to the left. It works fine when placed at the end of the document but not in between other chunks and text.